# How to remove annoying background in webstorms app

Tags: webstorm

Ok this is annoying and driving me crazy... I can find all types of options for fonts/colors/etc, but can't seem to get this to go away. Notice the green background around.. or well, in between a code section. Does anyone know how to get rid of this? Webstorms

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it appeared to be the "Injected language fragment" setting.

[image]

Comment: You saved me several headaches. It was driving me crazy. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of just removing a background (which has special meaning) wouldn't it be MUCH better to remove a cause that made this background appear in such unusual location in first place?

Comment: @LazyOne - When you inject a script reference, as it helps with intellisense, etc. this is the cause. So removing the "cause" isn't really relevant in this case as the cause was a good thing. The color just drive me crazy is all.

Comment: @user1447679 It's fine when you actually inject on purpose. But in your screenshot it's rather "WTF is this?" / wrong injection. So now, when you inject wrong language in wrong place, you may be saying "why this stupid IDE shows me these errors that have no relation to my perfectly valid code" -- you may simply not notice that there is an injection in place. That's all what I wanted to mention.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I was about to break my computer if not for your awesome answer!